# Storing XML in Database

Tags: sql-server, xml

Our system comprises of various components. Data flow in the system in form of XML . Each component process the XML , and add some content to it , and pass it to next component.

I want to store all the XML versions.The XML size is 250-300 KB . also there are fairly 20 versions of XML for one single transaction.Also the transactions could be in millions.

Am looking for the alternatives of the storage of this kind of XML data .What If I will store the XML in DB. Will that be an efficient way?

Also , if I will store the XML in DB , is there any way to search the XML based on it's content . And how efficient it would be.

Any thoughts would be a help.

Comment: *Fairly large - 250-300KB* - the `XML` datatype can handle **up to 2 GB** of data! 300KB is **nothing** ..... go ahead - store that XML ! And yes, you can use native XQuery to get bits and pieces from that XML

Comment: I do understand 300KB is nothing . But if there would be 20 millions around XML of that size , then DB storage will grow .Also These transactions will grow with time.

Comment: Where would you save the data otherwise? 20 million x 300 KB is about 6TB. I guess it depends on the time frame you wish to keep the data. Save current XML files you want indexed in the DB. Archive old XML on a file system. Archived files could be compressed to save disk space.

Answer (score 0):

Since your data flows are going to be in small chunks of 250-300 KB, it makes sense to save them in the DB xml or nvarchar (max) field, like marc mentioned can store upto 2GB data.The xml data type will validate the  XML to be well formed, so you have that advantage as well.
You can also consider to index your xml column, if you are retrieving large xml data.
Further, you can also be able to take advantage of [XQuery Language](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189075(v=sql.120).aspx) to search xml content.
In terms of what would be efficient, if you are simply storing the xml files, then keeping it in files sytem folder would work well, otherwise store it in the database. 
Hope this helps